# How to let bot Access User's PC Botframework SDK3 C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to know how to let my bot access user's PC and do something.
For example, I want to my bot create a CSV file and place it to user's PC.

I know it's not not safe. 
But I want to know whether it is possible to do like that in a safe way? like though another application? Or send a html table in the chat, then some software will catch it, change it to a CSV file in the local.

Comment: If I was to become aware a bot is doing that, I'd search for the developer. And **would** find him ...

Comment: Hi @胡华夫, if you were a bot app user, when that bot create/save/install a file on your computer, would you think it is a safe and trustworthy behavior? I suggest that you can send a URL that points to your file from your bot to user(s), and let user(s) decide whether receive and run this file on his computer.

Comment: @FeiHan You are right. It's not safe..That's why I accept your answer in another question. But my client is desiring something like that. Maybe I should ask is it possible to do like that in a safe way?

Comment: _"my client is desiring something like that"_ Life could be so easy if it were not for those clients ... :D No, seriously: Look for an alternative to that. This is really not an application to use a bot for. Some serious consultation is needed at the client's.

Comment: Would prompting for a download and then allowing the user to agree to save it meet this requirement? [Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-receive-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) generally cover that use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know how to let my bot access user's PC and do something.

That's hopefully not possible.

Prepare your CSV and sent it as an attachment or a link